# Upgrading To Spring Boot 2.4.0 Breaks Legacy Applications

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-cloud, junit5

I'm upgrading a set of legacy applications to Spring Boot 2.4.0, running on OpenJDK 8, deployed to Pivotal Cloud Foundry.

The app and all its unit tests ran perfectly under Spring 2.3.4-RELEASE before I started this upgrade.

There was work to be done right off the bat: Spring Boot 2.4.0 brings in JUnit 5.x, so I had to fix all the JUnit 4.x tests to use the new annotations and classes.

After fixing all the tests I tried to run in IntelliJ 2020.2.  All the tests failed, for the same reason: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext`.  The root of the stack trace gives this cause:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata
```

They removed a fundamental class from Spring Boot for the sake of Kubernetes, from the sound of it.  I'm not sure I see why.

I did a Google search and found [this](https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/config-file-processing-in-spring-boot-2-4) explanation and fix.

I added `spring.config.use-legacy-processing` to my `application.yml` and a test `application.properties` file:

```
spring:
  config:
    use-legacy-processing: true
```

Still no joy - all the tests fail.

I'm confused by [other links](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/19860) I've seen.  Is this an issue with `spring-cloud-dependencies`?  I'm reading that there might an issue with the `Hoxton` version.  Do I need to add it to my app?  It never needed this dependency before the upgrade:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Hoxton.SR9</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
```

The problem is bigger than the tests.  If I ignore them and try to run the app I still fail:

```
ERROR [main]: Application run failed |ApplicationName=Risk_Advisor | sourcedfrom=ERROR 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationPropertiesBeans' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]
```

The root cause is the same:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata
```

Comment: So, do you currently use any spring cloud dependencies or not? Also, it would be great to see some meaningful things like the whole pom.xml, *.yml files, and config classes.

Comment: That's a lot of stuff to post.  I think I've already posted meaning things.  Have you upgraded to Spring Boot 2.4.0?  If not, how will posting the pom help you answer?  I want to hear from folks on the Spring Boot project, but the GitHub issues page recommends that I start here.

Comment: Spring Cloud Hoxton is not compatible with boot 2.4.x

Comment: This app never needed Spring Cloud.  I don't have it in the pom now.  I'm asking if it's necessary b/c the other link talked about it.

Comment: @duffymo yes, I've already upgraded several projects to 2.4.0 and everything is ok including tests (I think I had some problems only with swagger). The whole pom might be helpful in terms of possible incompatible versions of the dependencies.

Comment: Thank you, @amseager.   I'm still not sure I can, because my app uses a bill of materials parent arrangement.  I can tell you that I've reviewed the dependencies to make sure that they're okay with 2.4.0.  I get the idea that I would benefit from talking to you, but I hesitate about posting too much of my employer's code on the web.

Comment: Ok, in this case I can only advice you to check the whole dependency tree for potential problems (incl. dependencies from your BOM) because it really looks like different Spring versions are present in the classpath. Also, don't waste time on playing with spring cloud - you definitely don't need to add it if you didn't have it before.

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace instead of a snippet. That will include the class that is the actual culprit trying to instantatie/needing that class. If it is really a Spring Cloud class (pulled in by some other dependency) you cannot upgrade as there is currently no Spring Cloud version compatible with Spring Boot 2.4.

Comment: Facing same issue post upgrade to 2.4.2
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.2</version>
 </parent>
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1543

Comment: please use <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.1</spring-cloud.version>

Answer (score 4):

when ever you do upgrades on spring, pls always look at the [spring / cloud compatibility matrix](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud) and then upgrades the versions for both spring and cloud accordingly:

Also, pls note that you may not have added spring cloud as direct dependency but it may be coming into your final jar as a *transitive dependency* so its always better to add below spring cloud dependency as direct dependency management in your pom to stay away from any conflicts:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.cloud-version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Good advice, Dean. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when migrating to **Spring Boot 2.4.4** which forced me to migrate to **Spring Cloud 2020.0.1** as well. In my case, the error was due to *Bootstrap*, provided by `spring-cloud-commons`, not being any longer enabled by default. I had to re-enabled it by adding the following new starter in my `build.gradle` file as stated [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Spring-Cloud-2020.0-Release-Notes#breaking-changes):

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap'
```

You say your app doesn't use Spring Cloud, so I'm not sure why you ended up facing which seems to be the same issue. Hopefully this workaround might work for you and help out others using Spring Cloud.

---

To fix the failing JUnit 4 tests, I have just added it as a dependency:

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error for JUnit 4 tests after migration my project to Spring Boot 2.5.6. Adding JUnit 4 dependencies did not fix this error as well as migration JUnit 4 tests to JUnit 5. My  project does not define Spring Cloud dependencies in build.gradle so in order to find where those dependencies come from I simply ran gradle command:

```
gradle dependencyInsight --dependency org.springframework.cloud
```

and saw that spring cloud dependencies were pulled within one of the custom libraries. Upgrade spring cloud dependencies to a [compatible version](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Spring-Cloud-2020.0-Release-Notes) there and reimport custom library fixed the error.